# efficient way to generate edges from a list of vertices

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

Given a list of vertices,in this case strings, is there any way more efficient than doing 2 nested cycles like

```py
for word in vertices:
    for other_word in vertices:
        # Check if the vertices are connected and add edge
        weigth = get_weigth(word,other_word)
        if weigth != -1:
            # add the edge
```

and without altering the data structure and assuming that `vertices` is sorted?

I tried the following

```py
for word in vertices:
    for other_word in vertices:
        if other_word<=word:
            continue
        else:
            # Check if the vertices are connected and add edge
```

but for large lists the performance is way too slow.

Edit:
To check if two vertices are connected i have a function like

```py
def get_weight(word1,word2):
    weight=-1
    if isAnagram(word1,word2) :
        weight = 1
    elif one_letter_diff(word1,word2):
        weight = 2
    # other function, but 
    return weight
```

i'm sure improvement on those function are possible, but it's not the point of the thread.

Also a sample the vertices is

```
a
aa
aaa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
...
```

the output should be the shortest path between 2 given words(using dijkstra for that).

Comment: Is every vertex supposed to be connected to every other vertex?  Because that certainly is an O(N^2) operation.

Comment: To avoid duplications, you can do `for i,word in enumerate(vertices):` / `for other_word in vertices[i+1:]:`, but it's still O(N^2).

Comment: All the vertex could or could not be connected so, yes is basically an O(n^2) operation becouse i have to check all the possibilities. Thats why i was asking if improvement are possible to what i'm actually doing. The rules to generate the weigth are basically some string manipulation rules so maybe in this istance but not that i can think of

Comment: There's no silver bullet here.  If you have 10,000 vertices, you will have to make 50,000,000 comparisons.

Comment: How do you know if two vertices are connected? That's the one relevant information which you did not include in your question.

Comment: Also since this is python, if you're going to use loops like this, I strongly suggest looking at [module itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Here, `from itertools import combinations; for (word, other_word) in combinations(vertices, 2): ...`

Comment: What are your sample input and sample output?

Comment: I edited the post, please look at that for the answers to your question

Comment: Ah, well, definitely, there is room for optimisation here. If word1 is an anagram of word2, and word1 is an anagram of word3, there there is no need to check whether word2 is an anagram of word3.

Comment: For instance, if you do: `anagrams = {}; for word in vertices: anagrams.setdefault(''.join(sorted(word), []).append(word)` then `anagrams` will look like this: `{'dgo': ['dog', 'god'], 'aah': ['aah', 'aha', 'haa'], ...}` and this is linear, not quadratic.